# Qiskit result per shot

Tags: qiskit, experimental-realization, ibm-quantum-devices, qiskit-runtime

I want to run a simple circuit with one qubit and a hadamard gate on a Quantum Machine. I want the result of every shot in a list.
It works with a simulator and the get_memory function but this function can‘t be used on IBM Quantum Machines.
Maybe somebody can help me

Thanks :)

Comment: To my understanding the memory feature is not available for all the devices but it is available for some. I think you can see which of your devices support it by using the `backends` method filtering. Also remember to set `memory=True` when you call `run`.

Answer (score 0):

Some backends do support the `memory` function. First check which all backends you have access to , using:

```python
# Initialize your account 
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
service = QiskitRuntimeService()
 
service.backends()
```

Then shortlist the `least_busy` and the one with `memory`, using this:

```python
backends = service.backends(filters=lambda x: x.configuration().open_pulse and x.status().operational,memory=True)

backend = least_busy(backends)
print("Selected the least busy backend: ", backend.name)
```

This will give you the least busy backend that has the `memory` function.

Now just write the code and run, like how you do in simulator:

```python
q = QuantumRegister(1)
c = ClassicalRegister(1)
circ = QuantumCircuit(q, c)

circ.h(q)

circ.measure(q,c)

job = execute(circ, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots=100, memory=True)
data = job.result().get_memory()
print(data)
```

and now for the actual quantum backend:

```python
sampler = Sampler(session=backend)
job = sampler.run(circ,shots=10,memory=True)
data = job.result().get_memory()
print(data)
```

This will give you what you want.